# "Update profile info" link allows to open multiple instances in stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile

The "Update profile info" link in the [stackexchange.com - user profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), allows to open multiple instances.
Will it restrict to open only one instance all the time?

GIF for the same:

> [image: Update profile info]

Comment: I think a more precise description of the bug is that it doesn't discard the pop-up when clicking outside its bounds.